# Проблема с Interceptor в Java Spring

Tags: java, spring, rest

У меня имеется Interceptor который проверяет входящие запросы и проверяет значение, но даже когда значение true он всегда возвращает мне Bad Request не доходя до нужного метода в контроллере.

```
 @Component(value = "authInterceptor")
public class AuthInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

@Autowired
UserManager userManager;

Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(AuthInterceptor.class);

@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("Interceptor");
    if (!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        InputStream body = request.getInputStream();
        if (body != null) {
            log.info("Body is not null.");
            JsonObject model = new JsonParser().parse(new InputStreamReader(body)).getAsJsonObject();
            System.out.println(model.get("login").getAsString());
            if (!userManager.isRegisteredLogin(model.get("login").getAsString())) {
                log.error("Login is not authorized");
                response.sendError(401);
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        } else {
            log.error("Login is not authorized body is empty");
            response.sendError(401);
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {

}

@Override
public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {

}
}
```

Метод в контроллере

```
 public ResponseEntity currentDate() {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(userController.getServerTime(), HttpStatus.OK);
  }
```

Этот метод не будет вызван

Comment: А что Вы еще хотите увидеть, у Вас пустая функция posstHandle

Comment: А что должно быть в postHandle, она вроде отвечает за проверку после  запроса. Метод postHandle вызывается после того как контроллер отработал и вернул результат. а он даже до контроллера не доходит